# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged always fired/triggered even disabled

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I got two comboxBox with SelectedIndexChanged event enabled.
In the comboBox2 i want to change the SelectedValue of comboBox1, and that works, but the SelectedIndexChanged of comboBox1 is always triggered even i explicit disabled that.
And the code in selectedIndexChange of the ComboBox1 overwrite what I do in the ComboBox2, that the problem.
I've tried hundreds ways to avoid that but anything works, the event always occurs.

Bellow is my code of ComboBox1:

```cs
private void cmbBeneficiario_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
            if (!cb.Focused)
            {
                return;
            }
            systemChange = true;
            if (cnpjChange)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmbBeneficiario.Text) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmbBeneficiario.Text))
                {
                    var beneficiarioApoliceBeneficiario =
                        averbacaoController.GetApoliceBeneficiario(cmbBeneficiario.Text);
                    var apolices = beneficiarioApoliceBeneficiario.Select(x => x.numero_apolice).ToList();
                    cmbApolice.DataSource = apolices;
                    cmbApolice.DisplayMember = "numero_apolice";
                    cmbApolice.Invalidate();
                    Refresh();
                    cmbApolice_SelectedIndexChanged(this, e);

                    var listBene = beneficiariosList;
                    var filteredList = listBene.Where(x => x.nome_beneficiario == cmbBeneficiario.Text).ToList();
                    cbbCNPJBeneAverb.DisplayMember = "cnpj_beneficiario";
                    cbbCNPJBeneAverb.DataSource = filteredList;
                }

                CarregaBeneficiarioPerfil();

                systemChange = false;
            }
        }
```

The comboBox2 code (note that I disabled the event of combobox1):

```cs
private void cbbCNPJBeneAverb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cnpjChange = true;
            ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
            if (!cb.Focused)
            {
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($@"Old ID {cmbBeneficiario.SelectedValue}");
            var beneficiario = averbacaoController.GetBeneficarioByCNPJ(cbbCNPJBeneAverb.Text, cmbBeneficiario.Text);
            cmbBeneficiario.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cmbBeneficiario_SelectedIndexChanged);
            if (cbbCNPJBeneAverb.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                cmbBeneficiario.SelectedValue = beneficiario.id_beneficiario;
                CarregaBeneficiarioPerfil();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($@"New ID {cmbBeneficiario.SelectedValue}");
            Console.WriteLine($@"Tinha que ser o ID {beneficiario.id_beneficiario}");
            cmbBeneficiario.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cmbBeneficiario_SelectedIndexChanged);
            cnpjChange = false;
        }
```

Printscreen of my debug:
[image]

Comment: Consider using the [`SelectionChangeCommitted` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted) instead. This will only get triggered when the user manually selects an item.

Comment: You can use: 1) a temporary class-scope variable `private bool cb1EventIgnore = false;`, 2) set it to `cb1EventIgnore = true` just before the code `cmbBeneficiario.SelectedValue = beneficiario.id_beneficiario;` 3) in the handler `cmbBeneficiario_SelectedIndexChanged` to check like this: `if(cb1EventIgnore) return;` at the beginning.

Comment: It may also be the case that elsewhere in your code you have subscribed to the event more times than you have unsubscribed from it. `-= handler` works the same way as `-= 1` for an int. If you had two subscribed before it will only remove one. You can use `GetInvocationList()` on the event to check if anything is still attached, and if this is the issue then look for the offending additions elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of attempts, bellow are the piece of code that solved my question:

```cs
cmbBeneficiario.Enabled = false;
```

Simple like this, i dont know why c# was not able to not trigger the event even I explicit told him to.

Answer (score 0):

As my comments above, you can use a class-scope variable to do check:

1. Add a temporary class-scope variable:

```
    private bool cb1EventIgnore = false;
```

2. Set it to ture/false in `cbbCNPJBeneAverb_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
            if (cbbCNPJBeneAverb.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                cb1EventIgnore = true;
                cmbBeneficiario.SelectedValue = beneficiario.id_beneficiario;
                CarregaBeneficiarioPerfil();
                cb1EventIgnore = false;
            }
```

3. Check the value `cb1EventIgnore` in `cmbBeneficiario_SelectedIndexChanged` at the beginning:

```
        private void cmbBeneficiario_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(cb1EventIgnore) return;
            //your codes here
        }
```

Comment: Tks for your comment, but i already did thar, but don't works.